# ARD / ZDF reduced bill or no pay at all

Tags: tax-law, germany, health

I have many years now "Tinnitus". I have already visited a doctor and he told me that i can use a hearing device or i should do an operation, if things go worse.

A friend of mine said that as long i have tinnitus and wearing a hearing device is an option to relieve the problem, i am not obligated to pay for ARD/ZDF , which i pay the last years. I live and work in Germany the last 4 years.

Is it true? Is there any "Law" /Rule or an exception for these problems?

Answer (score 1):

Reductions of the "Rundfunkbeitrag" are based on § 4 Abs. 1, Abs. 2 [Rundfunkbeitragsstaatsvertrag](http://sl.juris.de/sl/gesamt/RdFunkBeitrStVtr_SL.htm#RdFunkBeitrStVtr_SL_rahmen):

> § 4 (1) Von der Beitragspflicht nach § 2 Abs. 1 werden auf Antrag folgende natürliche Personen befreit:
>
> [...]
>
> 10. taubblinde Menschen und Empfänger von Blindenhilfe nach § 72 des Zwölften Buches des Sozialgesetzbuches oder nach § 27 d des Bundesversorgungsgesetzes
>
> (2) Der Rundfunkbeitrag nach § 2 Abs. 1 wird auf Antrag für folgende natürliche Personen auf ein Drittel ermäßigt:
>
> 1. blinde oder nicht nur vorübergehend wesentlich sehbehinderte Menschen mit einem Grad der Behinderung von wenigstens 60 allein wegen der Sehbehinderung,
> 2. hörgeschädigte Menschen, die gehörlos sind oder denen eine ausreichende Verständigung über das Gehör auch mit Hörhilfen nicht möglich ist, und
> 3. behinderte Menschen, deren Grad der Behinderung nicht nur vorübergehend wenigstens 80 beträgt und die wegen ihres Leidens an öffentlichen Veranstaltungen ständig nicht teilnehmen können.
>
> Absatz 1 bleibt unberührt.

Maybe you can qualify for a reduction to 1/3 based on § 4 Abs. 2 Nr. 2: deaf or hearing impaired so that you cannot have sufficient communication even with a hearing device. But, as I understand you, you can communicate even without a hearing device. So you have to pay the full "Beitrag".

Informations on that can be found on the [website of the Beitragsservice](https://www.rundfunkbeitrag.de/buergerinnen_und_buerger/informationen/menschen_mit_behinderung/index_ger.html) and at many other places in the internet.

Comment: Translation: Being blind gives you 100% rebate. Being deaf or almost completely deaf, or people who are so disabled that they cannot go to any public events, get 2/3rds rebate.